# Recursive query for postgresSQL parent/child

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

Asking for a little help on a recursive query syntax, and of course result.

As you will see I have a table with category parent and child ( a parent can have infinite children). Querying the category dictionary (linked to a real category)

And I want to return only the last child of every category tree

Updated my code, and information

## EDIT

```
WITH RECURSIVE cat(id) AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        category_dictionary
            LEFT JOIN category_dictionary.category ON category.id
    WHERE
        category.parent is NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        cat
            LEFT JOIN cat.category ON category.id
    WHERE
        category.parent is NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cat
```

Table information:

- `Category_dictionary` is a table the join category on parameter category
- `Category` is the main table with Parent entry.

Sample data:

`category_dictionary` entry:

```
ID : name (Men) : category_id
```

`category` entries:

```
category_id : name : parent (null or category_id)
```

As a result I want all the last child of each category entries, I mean the category that doesn't have child.

Comment: Please add your error message and some sample data

Comment: Those LEFT JOIN's makes no sense, at all.

Comment: For LEFT JOIN you'd need an ON clause...

Comment: I ll try somethings and update,

Comment: Please give us some sample data and expected output

Comment: Edited with more informations, hope you ll anderstand ...

Comment: "*last child*" implies an ordering. What do you want to order the children by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive query is not needed to find the deepest children. Instead, one would look at entries that are not a parent (so no other child exists). Such entries ID is not included in the `parent` column.

You can then join this categories to other tables

```
SELECT *
FROM category cat
  JOIN category_dictionary cat_dic ON cat.id = cat_dic.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1 FROM category cat2
  WHERE cat2.parent = cat.id);
```